# Threshold and component GARCH (p,q)-M models augmented by past inflation and targeting dummy - Python code

Tags: python, parameters, dummy-variable, arch, fgarch

I am a university student trying to replicate the paper 'Inflation and inflation uncertainty in the United Kingdom, evidence from GARCH modelling' by A. Kontonikas and I am looking for guidance regarding my work on the GARCH models. Despite exploring various methods, I have encountered challenges in obtaining all the parameters outlined in the paper. In particular, while I have successfully obtained the parameters omega, alpha 1, and beta 1, there are additional parameters highlighted in the paper such as lambda1, lamda2 etc. (as per the attached screenshot) that I am struggling to incorporate into my GARCH model. I am uncertain about how to address this discrepancy and properly integrate the variance model into our framework.

Below, I have outlined the mean and variance equations, shared my initial code, and attached the relevant outputs. I have used a slightly different dataset from the paper.

[Mean equations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01Rgm.png)
[Conditional variance models](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mPNE.png)
[Output in the paper with the parameters I am missing highlighted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkIO5.png)
[Dataframe with just variables used in the OLS model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzC3l.png)
[GARCH by using this dataframe containing, monthly OLS model variables, in the arch_model equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWuSG.png)

I would be very grateful for any guidance on how I might obtain the parameters for the additional terms specified in the paper and the construction of the models. Many thanks.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels.stats.api as sms
from arch import arch_model

# Create a sample dataframe
data = {
    'Date': pd.date_range('1972-01-01', '2002-12-31', freq='M'),
    'Monthly_cpi': np.random.rand(372),  # Replace this with your actual Monthly_cpi data
}
cpi_df_monthly = pd.DataFrame(data)
cpi_df_monthly['log_first_diff'] = 100 * (np.log(cpi_df_monthly['Monthly_cpi']) - np.log(cpi_df_monthly['Monthly_cpi'].shift()))

# Set the 'Dummy' column
cpi_df_monthly['Dummy'] = 0
cpi_df_monthly.loc[cpi_df_monthly['Date'] > '1992-09-30', 'Dummy'] = 1

# Set up variables dataframe
cpi_df_monthly_modeldf = cpi_df_monthly[['Date', 'log_first_diff', 'xt_1', 'xt_3', 'xt_6', 'xt_12', 'Dummy']].dropna()

# Monthly model with Dummy
monthly_model_dummy = smf.ols(
    formula="log_first_diff ~ Dummy * xt_1 + xt_3 + xt_6 + Dummy * xt_12",
    data=cpi_df_monthly_modeldf
).fit()
print(monthly_model_dummy.summary())

# Set up variables dataframe for ARCH
cpi_df_monthly_variables = cpi_df_monthly_modeldf[['xt_1', 'xt_3', 'xt_6', 'xt_12', 'Dummy']]
cpi_df_monthly_variables['Dummy*xt_1'] = cpi_df_monthly_variables['xt_1'] * cpi_df_monthly_variables['Dummy']
cpi_df_monthly_variables['Dummy*xt_12'] = cpi_df_monthly_variables['Dummy'] * cpi_df_monthly_variables['xt_12']

# Monthly (1,1) ARCH model
mod = arch_model(
    y=cpi_df_monthly_modeldf.log_first_diff,
    x=cpi_df_monthly_variables[['xt_1', 'xt_3', 'xt_6', 'xt_12', 'Dummy*xt_1', 'Dummy*xt_12']],
    mean="ARX",
    vol='GARCH',
    p=1,
    q=1,
)
res = mod.fit(disp='off')
print(res.summary())
```

Comment: Ideally you would add code blocks with a minimum working example, so folks here can have a starting point to help you with your particular issue. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for further information  on how to do this.

Comment: @tdpu thank you very much for your suggestion, really appreciate it. I have now uploaded a minimum working example.

Comment: I believe your question is more appropriate on https://datascience.stackexchange.com/. I'm not really an expert in this field, but it appears that the Kontonikas paper introduces an _augmented_ GARCH model, where they've introduced lambda, mu etc (these additional parameters that you're missing). It appears as if the `arch` package allows you to create new/augmented models or introduce volatility. This _sounds like_ what you're looking for, but again, I'm not an expert, so take it with a grain of salt.

Comment: The package docs are sparse on how to actually implement these new/augmented models, but it's mentioned here: https://arch.readthedocs.io/en/latest/univariate/volatility.html#writing-new-volatility-processes

Comment: @tdpu thank you very much, that is very helpful!